# How to colour multiple residues in Pymol?

Tags: pymol

We can use

```
color yellow, resi 3
color yellow, resi 3-8
```

to colour one residue or a range of residues. But what if I want to colour residue 3-8 and 10-20, how to write it?

Also, my protein has two chains, light chain (L) with 100 residues and heavy chain (H) with 100 residues. How to colour the residue 10-20, 30-40 of light chain, and the residue 5-10, 20-30 of heavy chain in one go?

Comment: What you’ve written isn’t valid Python code. Is this in Pymol or similar?

Comment: @KonradRudolph it is Pymol code (you can use python with pymol but in the GUI you can type pymol code)

Comment: I don't think that python is an appropriate tag for this post.  This really isn't a bioinformatics question.

Comment: there is no tag called "pymol", and where else would you recommend?

Comment: @Bioathlete why wouldn't this be a bioinformatics question? Where would you have such question otherwise?

Comment: It is a general question for the use of a tool.  It belongs in a mailing or user list for that tool.

Comment: of course each software may have its own mailing list, like I use Gromacs as well. But we should still be able to ask questions here @Mitra thank you for changing it to tag pymol. I thought I do not have the authority as a newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: as I don't have any working version of pymol at the moment,
I am not able to test the solution properly.
However, an easy way is to first create a selection, and then to color it:

```
select toBecolored, resi 3-8
color yellow, toBecolored
```

Regarding the L/H chain part, if they are effectively annotated as L and H, something like the following should work:

```
select toBeColored, ((i. 10-20 or i. 30-40) and c. L ) or ((i. 5-10+20-30) and c. H)
color yellow, toBeColored
```

Combining both commands is probably possible as:

```
color yellow, ((i. 10-20 or i. 30-40) and c. L ) or ((i. 5-10+20-30) and c. H)
```

Pymol allows synonyms (eg. resi and i.  or chain and c.).

The following pages may be also helpful:

- [Pymol wiki: help on Selection](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Selection_Algebra)
- [SourceForge](http://pymol.sourceforge.net/newman/user/S0220commands.htm)

And the two following links, if you want to get a bit deeper in proper programming with python for pymol (as they can provide you with inspiration):

- [Pymol wiki: plugins](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Category:Plugins)
- [Pymol scripts](https://github.com/Pymol-Scripts/Pymol-script-repo)

Comment: @Llopis: Thank you for the edit! It's a lot clearer now :)